# How to make the picture in the background change with the main slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

There is a usual slider with text information. How to make so that when changing the slide with the text the background picture itself also changes? How to implement this? I use slick-slider. But the text "static text here" with a white background should not change with the slider. It is important. I am interested in this implementation and its possibility in principle.

```js
$('.js-slider').slick({
    appendArrows:$('.head-slider .js-arrows'), // Class For Arrows Buttons
     prevArrow:'<span class="arrow arrow_prev arrow_lg"></span>',
     nextArrow:'<span class="arrow arrow_next arrow_lg"></span>',
     autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
 });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.head-slider {
  max-width: 786px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(195, 158, 158, 0.7);
  margin: auto 0;
}
.head-slider p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 28px;
  max-height: 165px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.arrows {
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  right: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.arrows_main {
  top: inherit;
  right: 0;
}
.slider-item {
  margin: 55px;
  min-height: 342px;
  max-height: 342px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-top: 2px solid #c96217;
  border-right: 2px solid #c96217;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.arrow_next:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow_prev:after {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
.text {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1539567601-bf304c363f16?ixlib=r0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=7aee0ae43485302fd9e03461549a1459&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3891&q=80)">
  <div class="head-slider">
    <div class="arrows arrows_main js-arrows"></div>
    <div class="slider js-slider">
      <div class="slider-item">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus soluta inventore nisi tempore! In deleniti nobis, incidunt doloremque quia labore vero odio, accusantium laborum, necessitatibus perspiciatis minima esse itaque! Fuga, dolore animi esse voluptatibus recusandae assumenda sed praesentium eos ex!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe porro qui sint, obcaecati eius excepturi! Cumque accusamus numquam maiores dolorum quaerat suscipit cum placeat praesentium.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, quasi.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    static text here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could set a different background image on each `slider-item`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following. It sounds like you want two things. 1. An image slider. 2. Text in front of the image slider that won't move. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Jacob Yes, i need that: 1. .head-slider must have the same size and color as it is now. 2. The backround-image change with the text of .slider-item of .head-slider. 3 But the text under slider I should not change. But it should be located in the picture in .wrap.

Comment: @QuentinVeron, slider-item - must measure: 786px on 249px. But background-image must measure: 100% on 100vh.

Comment: @Dan you can use onchange event and add class to wrap div.. like img1 img2 etc or just add 3 divs with position absolute inside wrap and keep it hidden. using onchange event add active class based on index. i hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Good question Dan,

One way to handle this is by placing a "cover" over your slider. Use absolute positioning to place a div over your slider. Then, you can place text in front of the slider, while having the slider rotate images in the background.

I went ahead and added a snippet to make my answer more clear.

https://codepen.io/jacobshenning/pen/qJVMQa

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="cover">
    Cover Text
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div id="ImageOne"></div>
    <div id="ImageTwo"></div>
    <div id="ImageThree"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 400px;
}

.cover {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#ImageOne {
  background-image: url('http://hwr.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/placeholder-dark-600-400-729dad18518ecd2cd47afb63f9e6eb09.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 300px;
}
#ImageTwo {
  background-image: url('http://gbaproducts.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/img-placeholder-dark-vertical.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 300px;
}
#ImageThree {
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHdqxo4BzJeS6EZkWzm9lqnmikKnGUXBsTAm1V55j3IWAfMn2daQ');
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slick();
});
```